# React ckeditor typeerror: cannot read properties of null reading 'getattribute'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ckeditor

#### typeerror: cannot read properties of null reading 'getattribute'

I am working on the React project using CkEditor.
I want to customize the tool of CkEditor
When I looked up the official document, I read that the existing package should be included, I finished installing additional, and there are currently no errors in the vcode.

By the way, the error below appears in the console window because "Ckeditor" is not rendered on the screen after starting npm, so can I ask for your advice?

#### Error Code

[image]

#### My code

```
import React from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';

import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-decoupled/src/decouplededitor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
...

interface EditorProps {
    data: any;
    onChange: any;
    uploadFolder?: string;
    uploader?: string;
}

const Editor = ({
    data,
    onChange,
    uploadFolder = '',
    uploader = '',
}: EditorProps) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <CKEditor
                data={data}
                onChange={onChange}
                editor={DecoupledEditor}
                onReady={(editor: any) => {
                    editor.ui
                        .getEditableElement()
                        .parentElement.insertBefore(
                            editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
                            editor.ui.getEditableElement(),
                        );
                }}
                config={{
                    plugins: [
                        Essentials,
                        Paragraph,
                        Bold,
                        ...
                    ],
                    toolbar: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        ...
                    ],
                    fontSize: {
                        options: [19, 'default', 21....],
                    },
                    alignment: {
                        options: ['justify', 'left', 'center', 'right'],
                    },
                    table: {
                        contentToolbar: [
                            'tableColumn',
                            'tableRow',
                            'mergeTableCells',
                            'tableProperties',
                            'tableCellProperties',
                        ],
                    },
                    image: {
                        resizeUnit: 'px',
                        toolbar: [
                            'imageStyle:alignLeft',
                            'imageStyle:full',
                            'imageStyle:alignRight',
                            '|',
                            'imageTextAlternative',
                        ],
                        styles: { options: ['full', 'alignLeft', 'alignRight'] },
                        upload: { types: ['JPEG', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'PNG'] },
                    },
                    simpleUpload: {
                        uploadUrl: '/uploadFile',
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {
                            'upload-folder': uploadFolder || 'root',
                            'upload-editor': uploader || '',
                        },
                    },
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Editor;
```